# Creating an object and assigning it an associated object to it from a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, crud

I have Tools and Projects in my database. Projects belong to Tools & one Tool has one Project. I have numerous Tools already in my database.

When creating a Project I want to be able to assign it a Tool as well. The tricky thing is that a Tool is referenced by the tool_id in the database while users only know the Tool's names.

So when I create a Project I want to be able to pass in a tool_name and then somehow figure out which tool that is and create the project with the proper tool assigned to it.

Here is  my code so far, as you can see it will not work. As I take a tool_name in my new Project form but my strong params are expecting a tool_id not a tool_name

How would you solve this?

I have a form

```
<%= form_for [@project], :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <%= f.label :tool_name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :tool_name, class:'form-control' %>
</div>
```

In my project controller I have the following create method and strong parameters

```
def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
end

private

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name, :tool_id)
end
```

My Project table is the following:

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "tool_id"
end
```

My Tool table:

```
create_table "tools", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "tool_name"
end
```

In my Project model I have: `belongs_to :tool`
In my Tool model I have: `has_one :project`

Comment: It is better to provide a dropdown for tools, instead of text_field.

Comment: Yeah I will do dropdown eventually, but first I need to be able to understand how to do this so I can do dropdowns as well.. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would provide a dropdown instead with the tools available. Something like:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:tool_id, Tool.all, :id, :name) %>
```

If the list of tools is large you might be better off with autocomplete, but that depends on your application.